When using the String.Remove() method, what am I missing?
I'm relatively new to C#, and am working through a problem whereby I need to strip out all the non-alphanumeric characters within a string.
string thestr = "Hello, my name is Adam";
thestr = thestr.ToLower();
for (int i = 0; i<thestr.Length; i++)
{
    if (Char.IsPunctuation(thestr, i) == true||Char.IsWhiteSpace(thestr, i) == true)
    {thestr = thestr.Remove(i, 1);}
}
Console.WriteLine(thestr);

Currently it generates this - "hello mynameisadam"
The above is the code I was using, and my logic was it would loop through each character within thestr and then if that char was either punctuation or white space, it would remove it.
That clearly doesn't happen for the whole string, and I'm willing to put money on it being a relatively simple fix, but I can't see what I've missed to have it do it for part of the string.

When you delete the , at index 5 the adjacent space shifts to index 5, as the next loop looks at index 6 the space is ignored.

If you are modifying the string "in place" then you should do it in reverse order, i.e. starting at the last character and working towards the first. This will avoid the issue where removing a character moves all the following characters one place nearer the beginning, thus invalidating your loop index.

A suggestion, don't use strings in these situations, use String builder. It doesn't solve your problem though.

There may be other ways to replace punctuation/whitespace in a string, but specifically with regards to the method being used here...
The reason that one remaining space character wasn't removed was because of how the loop is structured.  i is going from 0 to the length of the string, but the string is changing as the loop iterates.  Specifically:

At an i of 5, the character ',' is encountered.
The character at index 5 is removed from the string.
(At this point the new string has a ' ' character at index 5.)
i is incremented to 6 and the loop continues.

So that space character was never examined.  The loop effectively skipped it, and would do so for any two consecutive target characters.
One simple approach for this specific problem would be to loop from the end to the beginning, rather than from the beginning to the end.  That way i is always decrementing and always goes to the immediate previous character, regardless of any changes made to the string after that character.
Basically, this:
for (int i = thestr.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)

Which would change the process for those two consecutive target characters to:

At an i of 6, the character ' ' is encountered.
The character at index 6 is removed from the string.
i is decremented to 5 and the loop continues.
At an i of 5, the character ',' is encountered.
The character at index 5 is removed from the string.
etc.


The complication is due to the way you're modifying the "input". Some alternative approaches include:
string thestr = "Hello, my name is Adam";
thestr = thestr.Replace( ",", "" ).Replace( " ", "" );

Console.WriteLine( $"(1) {thestr}" );

thestr = "Hello, my name is Adam";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach ( char ch in thestr ) {
   if ( char.IsLetter( ch ) ) {
      sb.Append( ch );
   }
}  // end for.

Console.WriteLine( $"(2) {sb}" );
Console.ReadKey();

